Avoiding parallelism in scheduled Azure Container App Jobs
We have a scheduled Azure Container App Job that runs every minute. However, it may sometimes take significantly longer to complete. Initially, we expected that setting the following configuration in Bicep:
scheduleTriggerConfig: {
        cronExpression: '0/1 * * * *'
        parallelism: 1
        replicaCompletionCount: 1
      }

would ensure that only one replica would be running at any given time. The documentation is somewhat ambiguous since the Bicep documentation states that the parallelism parameter defines the "Number of parallel replicas of a job that can run at a given time." In contrast, the Azure Container App Job documentation states that parallelism is "The number of replicas to run per execution. For most jobs, set the value to 1."
Our experience aligns with the latter interpretation. Has anyone been able to configure scheduled Azure Container App Jobs to run in a truly non-parallel manner?


Avoiding parallelism in scheduled Azure Container App Jobs

In general, to avoid parallelism we use to define parallelism set to 1 which means we are restricting the job to perform one dedicated operation. which means defining parallelism to 1 is non parallelism.
However, sometimes job takes significantly longer to complete because the second operation starts only after completing the first one. You can also use replica time out to define how long the job is allowed to run before it's considered failed.
Configuration:
resource containerAppJob 'Microsoft.App/jobs@2023-05-01' = {
  name: 'demovkcontainerjob'
  location: 'East US'
  properties: {
    environmentId: managedEnv.id
    configuration: {
      triggerType: 'Schedule'
      replicaTimeout: 3600  // 1 hour timeout for the job in seconds
      replicaRetryLimit: 2
      scheduleTriggerConfig: {
        cronExpression: '0/1 * * * *'  
        parallelism: 1  
        replicaCompletionCount: 1
      }
    }
    template: {
      containers: [
        {
          image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/containerapps-helloworld:latest'
          name: 'demovkcontainerjob'
          resources: {
            cpu: json('0.25')
            memory: '0.5Gi'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

depolyment:



refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.app/2022-06-01-preview/containerapps?pivots=deployment-language-bicep
